# How to use motion and nginx together?

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, motion

I have a motion server on one of my pis that I can connect to locally. On the same pi, I have an nginx server that I can connect to by going to my custom domain over wifi.

Is there any way to embed the webcam stream in the nginx server without having to make the motion server accessible over wifi? (i.e. without having to forward any ports)

Answer (score 3):

Short: In motion version 4.2.2 still not possible (only half solution).

Long: I tried to add these lines to nginx.

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
  include proxy_params;
}

location /0/stream {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8081;
}
```

But the motion webpage adds the port at the end (hardcoded). Like domain.cz:8081/0/stream.

So only one option is to open port 8081 to world (without nginx proxying)